# r ggplot x axis color gradient labels/values

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I currently have a plot graph with ggplot2 which has values associated on each coordinate which is expressed by a color gradient. My x values are ordered and is there anyway to express a separate gradient just for the x axis labels?
For example

```
x    y   z
7.5  55  1000
7.5  20  2000
7.5  10  3000
3    70  2500
3    50  10000
3    25  1300
```

The graph is plotted with x,z with y being the gradient colour. I want to assign color gradient to x values along the x axis as shown in the image below.

[image]
[image]

Something similar to the graph would be great!

The code i used is pasted below

```
plot_data=read.table("Finalfile.txt",sep="\t",header=T)
plot_data=plot_data[,1:8]
#order data according to expression followed by gene id
order_data=plot_data[order(plot_data$exp,plot_data$gene,decreasing=TRUE),]

#convert gene ids to numeric, same number for each gene id
plot_data=transform(plot_data,id=as.numeric(factor(gene)))

#x y plot 
ggplot(plot_data, aes(gene, TSS, colour=met)) +
  geom_point(shape=15) + ylim(0,10000)+
  scale_colour_gradient(low="blue", high="red")+theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: Do you actually mean you want the x axis values to have a colour or do you want to add a coloured bar under the xaxis as in the linked image?

Comment: actually either is okay, what i want is to have a gradient colour associated with the x values (which I have but didnt show). However, having a bar under the axis that shows this would be perfect!!!

Comment: I've thought about this some more and see where you're coming from. Could you provide your datafile or a representation and I'll update the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've interpreted your request to mean you want to demonstrate the spread of data on the x-axis.

I think this could help.

```
require(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

x   <- c(7.5 ,7.5 ,7.5 ,3 ,3 ,3 )
z   <- c(1000,2000,3000,2500,10000,1300)
y   <- c(55  ,20  ,10  ,70  ,50  ,25  )

data <- data.frame(x,z,y)

main <-ggplot (data, aes( x = x, y = z, colour = y))+
    geom_point() +
    scale_color_gradient(limits = c(0, max(y)))+
    theme(legend.position=c(1,1),legend.justification=c(1,1))

density.x <- ggplot(data, aes(x), fill = "blue")+        
        geom_density(width = c(0, max(y)),  alpha = 0.5,binwidth =1,  position   = 'identity', fill = "blue")

grid.arrange(density.x,  main, ncol = 1, nrow =2 , heights= c(1,4))
```

This does not give the colouring you originally requested but still conveys the same information. You could experiment with different geoms for different representations.

See here for further expansion on the theme: http://www.r-bloggers.com/ggplot2-cheatsheet-for-visualizing-distributions/

Comment: ah thats the package i need!! thank you so much! the plot is wrong but I think a histogram will work great in my case!